# How can I avoid blinking notification update while changing button

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a Notification, which supports play,pause forward and back.

```
private static Notification createNotification(String interpret, String title, boolean paused) {
//  if (builder == null)
       builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(interpret);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 9, new Intent(context, ApplicationActivity.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_previous, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.MUSIC_PLAYER_INTENT).putExtra("resultcode", NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.PREVIOUS), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    if (paused)
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_play, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 2, new Intent(NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.MUSIC_PLAYER_INTENT).putExtra("resultcode", NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.PLAY), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    else
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_pause, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 3, new Intent(NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.MUSIC_PLAYER_INTENT).putExtra("resultcode", NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.PAUSE), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_next, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 1, new Intent(NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.MUSIC_PLAYER_INTENT).putExtra("resultcode", NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.NEXT), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        notification.tickerView = null;

    return notification;
}
```

Updating the notification:

```
 public static void update(String interpret, String title, boolean paused) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, createNotification(interpret, title, paused));
}
```

To avoid blinking on update, I´ve set the builder to a global variable and I reuse it on every update, which works great. but reusing it, means that also all buttons I´ve added are reused and there is no possibility to remove Actions I´ve added before.

The button change only works, if I reinitialize the NotificationCompat.Builder on every update, which means I get the blinking again.

How do I avoid blinking, but letting the button change?

EDIT:
Just checked out Rocket Player, they didn´t solve the problem too, but Google Play Music did

Comment: i don't understand how reusing the builder (which, btw, you don't in this code, probably a typo) can prevent the blinking, since the notification object is still a different one every time ?

Comment: I don´t know why, but it´s a fact. found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406730/updating-an-ongoing-notification-quietly

Comment: my understanding from the question you posted is that what prevents blinking is the use of the same ID

Comment: no, this doesn´t prevent it! As I said, using always the same builder prevents it, but it won´t let me change the existing look

Comment: are you absolutely certain of that ? because in its present state, you code does create a new builder at each run.

Comment: This are the two possibilities: 1.Comment out if (builder == null) to create each time a new builder object so that the button change can work but the notification is blinking, because it´s getting completely rebuild. 2.don´t comment if (builder == null) out to avoid blinking, but the buttons can´t be changed, they do persist in the actual state

Comment: you could always use reflexion to access the builder's actions list, but there's got to be another way

Comment: out of curiosity, could you post the part where you send the notification to the manager ?

Comment: I mean, I´m not the first one implementing such a notification. Looking to other media players, there seems to be no problem to manage it. ok I´ll update the main thread

Comment: This has been also my problem. I think the issue is that I create new notifiation, when I just want to refresh the UI. I am still searching for solution.

Answer (score 17):

Like Boris said, the problem is that a new notification will be build every update. 
My solution covers the same logic, but I use the `NotificationBuilder`...

here is the code:

```
if (mNotificationBuilder == null) {
            mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false);
        } else {
            mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message);
        }
```

keep in mind that `mNotificationBuilder` is a private field in the class.

Comment: This does not work in 2019 on Samsung S8/S10e(possible other as well).

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you create new notification every time you want to update. I had the same issue and it fixed when I did the following:

- retain the instance of the notification inbetween different calls of `createNotification`.
- set this instance to null every time it is removed from the notification bar.
- do the following code:

Code:

```
private static Notification createNotification(String interpret, String title, boolean paused) {
   if (mNotification == null) {
       // do the normal stuff you do with the notification builder
   } else {
      // set the notification fields in the class member directly
      ... set other fields.
      // The below method is deprecated, but is the only way I have found to set the content title and text
      mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
   }
   return mNotification;
}
```

And now when you call `notify` no blinking will appear:

```
manager.notify(0, createNotification(interpret, title, paused));
```

PS: I also faced a problem that if I executed `setLatestEventInfo` the large and small icons got scrwed up. That's why I did:

```
int tmpIconResourceIdStore = mNotification.icon;
// this is needed to make the line below not change the large icon of the notification
mNotification.icon = 0;
// The below method is deprecated, but is the only way I have found to set the content title and text
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotification.icon = tmpIconResourceIdStore;
```

Looking into Adnroid ccode this line `mNotification.icon = 0;` disables the icon screw up.

Comment: I retained the instance of NotificationBuilder to make the flickering of notification go away.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is a rather old question, but since I didn't found a solution anywhere else, I thought answering this now might help others with the same problem.

This problem is kind of tricky to begin with. I encountered it today as well, and being my stubborn self, I found a solution after searching and trying for a while.

### How to solve this problem:

In order to be compatible with API-Levels lower than 19, my solution is to use the `NotificationCompat` classes from the support-library.

As suggested by others, I keep the reference to the `NotificationCompat.Builder` for as long as the notification is required. The actions I use in my Notification are only added upon initial creation of the `Builder`, and those actions that will change depending on the situation, I also store in a private member of the service. Upon change, I re-use the `Builder` object and adjust the `NotificationCompat.Action` object according to my needs. Then I call the `Builder.getNotification()` or `Builder.build()` method, depending on API-level (probably not necessary due to the support-libs, but I didn't check that. If I can omit that, please write a comment, so I can improve my code ;)

Here's an example code of what I just described above:

```
public Notification createForegroundNotification(TaskProgressBean taskProgressBean, boolean indeterminate) {
  Context context = RewardCalculatorApplication.getInstance();

  long maxTime = TaskUtils.getMaxTime(taskEntry);
  long taskElapsedTime = TaskUtils.calculateActualElapsedTime(taskProgressBean);
  long pauseElapsedTime = taskProgressBean.getPauseElapsedTime();

  int pauseToggleActionIcon;
  int pauseToggleActionText;
  PendingIntent pauseToggleActionPI;
  boolean pauseButton = pauseElapsedTime == 0;
  if(pauseButton) {
    pauseToggleActionIcon = R.drawable.ic_stat_av_pause;
    pauseToggleActionText = R.string.btnTaskPause;
    pauseToggleActionPI = getPendingIntentServicePause(context);
  } else {
    pauseToggleActionIcon = R.drawable.ic_stat_av_play_arrow;
    pauseToggleActionText = R.string.btnTaskContinue;
    pauseToggleActionPI = getPendingIntentServiceUnpause(context);
  }

  String contentText = context.getString(R.string.taskForegroundNotificationText,
      TaskUtils.formatTimeForDisplay(taskElapsedTime),
      TaskUtils.formatTimeForDisplay(pauseElapsedTime),
      TaskUtils.formatTimeForDisplay(taskProgressBean.getPauseTotal()));


  // check if we have a builder or not...
  boolean createNotification = foregroundNotificationBuilder == null;
  if(createNotification) { // create one
    foregroundNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    // set the data that never changes...plus the pauseAction, because we don't change the
    // pauseAction-object, only it's data...
    pauseAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(pauseToggleActionIcon, getString(pauseToggleActionText), pauseToggleActionPI);
    foregroundNotificationBuilder
        .setContentTitle(taskEntry.getName())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(getPendingIntentActivity(context))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_action_done, getString(R.string.btnTaskFinish), getPendingIntentServiceFinish(context))
        .addAction(pauseAction);
  }

  // this changes with every update
  foregroundNotificationBuilder.setContentText(contentText);

  if(indeterminate) {
    foregroundNotificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
  } else {
    foregroundNotificationBuilder.setProgress((int) maxTime, (int) taskElapsedTime, false);
  }

  // if this is not the creation but the button has changed, change the pauseAction's data...
  if(!createNotification && (pauseButton != foregroundNotificationPauseButton)) {
    foregroundNotificationPauseButton = pauseButton;
    pauseAction.icon = pauseToggleActionIcon;
    pauseAction.title = getString(pauseToggleActionText);
    pauseAction.actionIntent = pauseToggleActionPI;
  }

  return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
         ? foregroundNotificationBuilder.getNotification() // before jelly bean...
         : foregroundNotificationBuilder.build(); // since jelly bean...
}
```

The variables `foregroundNotificationBuilder`, `pauseAction` and `foregroundNotificationPauseButton` are private members of the service class.
The `getPendingIntent...()` methods are convenience methods that simply create the `PendingIntent` objects.

This method is then called when I need to update the notification using the `NotificationManager`, as well as handed over to the service's `startForeground()` method. This solves the flickering and the problems with the not updatable actions in the notification.