# Update notification to remove chronometer (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to show a notification and update it over the course of its lifetime. In particular, I need to change certain flags, such as "show chronometer". For that, the documentation states that we should call `NotificationManager.notify()` with the same id.

So the idea is to have these methods:

```
private void showInitialNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    ...
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

private void addChronometerFlag() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    ...
    builder.setUsesChronometer(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

private void removeChronometerFlag() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    ...
    builder.setUsesChronometer(false);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

This works perfectly OK in Android 5.1 and 6.0, but **in Android 4.4** (and below, I guess?) **the chronometer is not removed**, although the content title, text, icon &c are updated correctly.

Any idea why?

I cannot use the same `Notification.Builder` object (for example as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538209/82788)) since I also need to update the actions available on the notification and there is no way to remove previously added actions to a Builder.

My use case is somewhat more complicated (it's a media player) but this is the minimum example of the bug I've been able to reproduce. It's also present, for example, in Google's [UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) sample -- works fine in Lollipop, but not in KitKat.

FWIW, the full example code is [here](https://gist.github.com/matiash/867160284fdb1575398d72e216e8fd9a).

Comment: Take a look at the `Notification` built by the builder. See what's in the `extras` `Bundle`. There should be an `EXTRA_SHOW_CHRONOMETER` `boolean` value in there. See whether it lines up with your `setUsesChronometer()` value.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare - I've checked the notification object returned by the builder and the extras are OK (i.e. `android.showChronometer` is either true or false as appropriate). However it's not working properly, don't know why.

Comment: Next, try replacing `NotificationManagerCompat` with `NotificationManager`. If the problem persists, then the problem presumably resides in the system, and there's nothing that you can do about it. If the problem goes away, you are running into a bug in `NotificationManagerCompat`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately it doesn't make a difference; looks like it's a platform bug indeed. I'll just have to avoid setting these flags for pre-Lollipop... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could perhaps `cancel()` the existing `Notification` first. That will trigger any ringtones and such again when you `notify()`, and so that may be worse than your current situation.

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem is, this is a "media player control" notification, so pressing the play/pause actions would cause the notification to flicker. I've tried it and the effect is indeed worse.